# Is __dirname unusable this way or is it undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I have set a variable that is shown below

`pathImage = __dirname + '/bot.jpg;`

I want to pass the value of `pathImage` to IconUrl from my .env file. This is how I do it. 
`var invite = new Welcome(process.env.IconUrl=pathImage, process.env.BotVersion);`

Finally, I'm getting this error from NodeJs

> [onTurnError]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 633

But, this works for me (setting path manually, not preferable way)
`var invite = new Welcome(process.env.IconUrl='C:/Users/Mackhem/Desktop/testBot/bot.jpg', process.env.BotVersion)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a few things that are off:

1. You're missing a `'` in `pathImage = __dirname + '/bot.jpg;` -- maybe just a typo
2. I believe that you're trying to call `process.env.IconUrl`, but you're setting it at the same time with `process.env.IconUrl=pathImage`

#### Here's the fix:

In your `.env` file:

```
IconUrl=bot.jpg
```

In your other file:

```
const pathImage = path.join(__dirname, '..', process.env.IconUrl);
var invite = new Welcome(pathImage, process.env.BotVersion);
```

*Note: You cannot use `__dirname` in the `.env` file since everything in the `.env` file gets converted to a string.*